# There are injustice in this world. Innocent animals and birds are put to death. Poor and weak people are tortured. Is God happy with this world?

Tags: gods

There are injustice in this world.  Innocent animals and birds are put to death.  Poor and weak people are tortured.  Is God happy with this world?

Comment: are you happy with being able to walk and run where you want ? because when you do, you crush many innocent ants under your foot. so, are you prepared to stop walking forever ?

Answer (score 1):

Our Scriptures and saints say that God created this world out of His Own Self just to enjoy infinite types and proportions of pains and pleasure.He was not satisfied while being alone. He Himself started playing in form of many :एकोऽहं वहु स्याम् meaning from One I shall become many.

We do not understand our real nature and so suffer.The spiritual practices are for getting the grace of God or the Self and get liberated from all these pleasures and pains. (Reference:Sri Ramakrishnakathamrita)

Comment: not everyone agree with your view god doesn't enjoy giving pain..

Comment: @PrasannaR its NOT giving pain. He is suffering the pain Himself

Comment: god never suffers himself.. that crux of Vedanta nobody needs a god who suffer just like us im cutting my argument here

Comment: @PrasannaR there are different concepts of Atma. The Supreme God never suffers